# reading and writing .xls file in arraylist

Tags: struts2

In my struts2 application, I met with a situation where I have to read .xls file and write it into an arraylist. The .xls file is of fixed format i.e no. of columns are fixed.
Please suggest me the best way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0516.html)